# Find $x$ and $n$ inequality

Tags: inequality

1. Find all $x\in\mathbb R$, that satisfy this inequality: $$\left|x^5-1\right|+\left|x^6+9\right|>0$$
2. Find all $n\in\mathbb Z$, that satisfy this inequality: $$\left|\frac{n+1}{2n+3}-\frac12\right|>\frac1{12}$$
   I just can't find the right answer.

Comment: Can you show the work you have done so we can understand the issue? regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that $|y|\ge 0$ for all $y$ and $|y|=0$ only if $y=0$. Thus we immediatley have $|x^5-1|+|x^6+9|\ge 0$ and we could only have $|x^5-1|+|x^6+9|\not> 0$ if $x^5-1=0$ and at the same time $x^6+9=0$, which is impossible (why?). In fact, when restricting to $x\in \mathbb R$, we immediately get $x^6+9\ne 0$ (why?)
2. Multiply both sides with $|12(2n+3)|$ (which is always $>0$) to get $|12(n+1)-6(2n+3)|>|2n+3|$, i.e. $6>|2n+3|$.

Comment: How did you get 6>|2n+3|from this |12(n+1)−6(2n+3)|>|2n+3|?Thank you very much!